# List all the elements of $\{C \in \mathcal{P}(\{0,1,2\}) : \{0,1\} \nsubseteq C\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm just really confused about what {0,1} not being contained in C would mean. Does it mean that the answer is all the elements of the powerset except for {0,1}, or does it mean the answer is all the elements that do not contain 0 or 1?

Comment: It is all subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$ such that at least one of $0$ or $1$ are missing from the subset.

Comment: So it would just be the empty set and {2}? @JMoravitz

Comment: Not at all.  Try looking at the opposite set... $\{C\in\mathcal{P}(\{0,1,2\})~:~\{0,1\}\subseteq C\}$.  This is the set of all subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$ such that it has both $0$ and $1$ as elements.  Do you see why this is the opposite set?  Do you see why this has no overlap with your original?  Do you see why all subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$ will satisfy exactly one of the conditions that they either *are* or *are not* a superset of $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Alternate leading question to hopefully get you to the right answer... Is $\{0,1\}\subseteq \{1\}$?  Is $\{0,1\}\subseteq \{1,2\}$?  You can repeat asking that question for all of the eight subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$.  Those $C$ for which you answer "*no, $\{0,1\}$ is not a subset of $C$*" will be the elements of your set you are asking about.  While true that $\{0,1\}$ is not a subset of $\emptyset$ and $\{0,1\}$ is not a subset of $\{2\}$, there are many more.

Comment: You seem to have incorrectly read the condition as $\{0,1\}\cap C = \emptyset$ which is not the case and is not how the condition should have been read.  Again, the condition is equivalent to "*at least one of $0$ or $1$ (possibly both, but possibly only one of them) is missing from the subset*", in yet other words "*it is not the case that both 0 and 1 are simultaneously members of the subset*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm still a little confused, but here's my understanding:  So $\emptyset$, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0,2}, {1,2} would be correct because {0,1} is not a subset of any of those elements? And {0,1,2} would not be included because {0,1} is a subset

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, that last explanation cleared it up a lot better for me, thank you!